# New release while ignoring EOL Ubuntu distro

Tags: ros, buildfarm, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kind of continuing from a discussion [Drop support for Wily](https://discourse.ros.org/t/drop-support-for-wily/727/8).

[MoveIt! release for Indigo is stuck at Ubuntu Saucy](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/389), which reached the [end of life in July 2014](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/17/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2014/).

Is there a way to make a release ignoring a particular EOL Ubuntu distros that are still supported by ROS (e.g. Saucy for Indigo, Wily for Kinetic)?

A potential workaround is [suggested](https://discourse.ros.org/t/drop-support-for-wily/727/6) but I'm not quite sure what steps exactly need to happen to do that.

I can't agree more that mending for EOL distros is nothing but a waste of time for all involved maintainers as discussed in the same thread...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250829/new-release-while-ignoring-eol-ubuntu-distro/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been no update since the referenced discourse discussion. So unfortunately no - at the moment you can't ignore EOL distros when releasing a ROS package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0